# Cannot set format of console log in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-log

I'm trying to setup boost.log into a project I have. I've followed the examples, but when I try to set a format, the compiler says that format is a read-only reference.

```
void init() {
    logging::add_console_log(
        std::cout,

        // Compiler says "const boost::parameter::keyword<keywords::tag::format>& is read-only reference".
        keywords::format = "%Timestamp% %Message%",

        keywords::severity = info
    );

    logging::add_common_attributes();
}
```

Comment: Well you could pin-point me what type of error this is. I'm not a beginner in software development (I'm an architect) and I pretty much understand most of the principles. I need to learn C++ to dev a lightweight GlusterFS replacement. Just tell me what kind of error this is and I won't make it ever again, thanks.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert in Boost, but I know that you're trying to modify a read-only variable, as the compiler appropriately tells you. That is basically the answer to your question.

Comment: From the documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_console_lo_idp52354704.html: format Specifies a formatter to install into the sink. May be a string that represents a formatter, or a formatter lambda expression (either streaming or Boost.Format-like notation).

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972818/how-to-change-the-default-formatting-with-boostlogboost-trivial-log. The guy does the same thing as me, yet it seems to work.

Comment: You're assigning a value to `keywords::format` and then evaluating that value into the `format` parameter.  Remove `keywords::format =` and you should be okay. Same applies for the other attempt below. Trust me, there are way too many things you seem not to understand about C++, and **really trust me**, C++ is one of the most complicated and feature-full languages ever conceived by mankind. There's a myth that says that no living person knows all of it. You should take a good time to get familiar with it. A Python background is useless here.

Comment: Nope, it's not even compiling. All examples on the boost site put keywords::format before this parameter.

Comment: Of course, it's not compiling because it's not *semantically* valid code (attempts to write to read only memory). However, it's syntatically valid, and in a very obscure way. The code in the answer you mentioned does effectively work. Again, I'm no expert in C++, but C++ is not a language to work with if you don't know it from the inside. It's not as intuitive as it seems first-hand, and it's way too easy to introduce code that compiles, but produces completely unexpected results. You should understand examples, not copy-paste them. Rule #1 is that templates can get way too complicated easily.

Comment: @KemyLand: This is how Boost.Log works. I advise against the holier-than-thou approach to teaching until you yourself have the slightest clue what you're talking about. :)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: I know the language, but not the bulky Boost libraries. The OP seems to know neither. Please be a little more respectful for my attempts in helping the OP, and then may I consider your empty and irrelevant suggestion.

Comment: @KemyLand: No, _I'm_ asking _you_ to be respectful. So far your comments to the OP have included phrases including: _"You should learn about the language itself before blindly attempting to write Boost code"_, _"Trust me, there are way too many things you seem not to understand about C++"_, _"**trust me**"_... which are somewhat ironic since you fundamentally misunderstood both the code and the question. Just a friendly suggestion to do some research yourself next time! :)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: I did never read the function's API. Maybe I didn't used the best words to the OP. However, I attempted to help him based on pitfalls I know he would fall on otherwise. Your presence here is purposeless and so far has helped no one to improve nothing. Please stop doing this.

Comment: Sigh. Pot meet kettle.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the nearest example? It could be you're missing a header file include. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_fmt_string.cpp

Comment: It's possible that `keywords::format` is in the wrong namespace. You might want to use the fully specified namespace : `boost::log::keywords::format`. This compiles for me... except I'm having trouble having the logger recognize `"%Severity%`... but that is a functional problem, not a compilation problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're experiencing a compiler bug. The `format` keyword, as any other keyword declared with `BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD` from [Boost.Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html), is indeed a constant reference. However, there is a const-qualified assignment operator in `boost::parameter::keyword`, which should be picked by the compiler.

As a workaround, you can try replacing the keyword with a call to `get` static function like this:

```
// Replace this:
keywords::format = "%Timestamp% %Message%"

// with this:
boost::parameter::keyword<keywords::tag::format>::get() = "%Timestamp% %Message%"
```

Also, please note that the attribute names are case sensitive, and the `add_common_attributes` function adds a "TimeStamp" attribute, not "Timestamp" (note the upper-case S).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the compiler still complains about the immutability of the instance.

Comment: What if you just construct the keyword in place? `boost::parameter::keyword<keywords::tag::format> format; format = "%Timestamp% %Message%";` Then, if nothing works, you can try constructing the sink manually and setting up it through the API (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.html), although you may get similar errors in other parts of the library. Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Nope. By the way, it does work, however CLion keeps flagging the line as an error. But the code compiles and work, without warning from gcc (-Wall -Wextra -Werror). I decided to stop the investigation and let it as is, since it works (CLion flags lot of boost code).

Comment: Most IDE-targeting code parsers have to cut some corners to provide a reasonable performance. They may flag valid code as errors or simply fail to parse. In my experience, parsers based on Clang (e.g. in QtCreator) provide the best robustness while having decent performance. BTW, next time it would be nice if you mention in the question that the error comes from the IDE and not the actual compiler.